# Connect iChat to SE Chat

Tags: support

Is is possible to connect the SE chat to iChat? I am not always on SE, but I am on iChat a fair amount.

Comment: No, I am 99% sure this is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SO Chat is custom-built, so it doesn't work with any other services.

However, given that the SO crowd consists of programmers, several projects have been proposed/begun to allow more functionality:

- [SO (chat) Plugin for Pidgin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82840/so-chat-plugin-for-pidgin)
- [Offer an XMPP method for chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat)
- [IRC access for the chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat/)

Unfortunately, none seem to have had much action lately, so I don't know the current status of any of them—but something along these lines will be your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for the links :-) Incidentally, is [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) the best venue for chatting about chat?